# Snowflake Max retention period for premier_plus_1 edition

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My organization has premier_plus_1 snowflake account and want to confirm what is the maximum allowed retention period for the same edition.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "premier_plus_1" - the different editions of Snowflake are Standard, Enterprise, Business Critical, VPS (unless something has changed recently and not been reflected in the documentation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Premier edition (although as NickW stated is not available any longer) used to be Standard edition with additional 24x365 support. (Standard Edition only had 9-5 support from Monday to Friday). (You can find a hint in the footnote here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/intro-editions.html#customer-support

Now Premier Edition is basically the same as standard edition, so the data retention time can be between 0 and 1 days. (+ 7 days of Fail-Safe). (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-time-travel.html#data-retention-period)

BR, TK

Answer (score 0):

Premier Plus is outdated edition, and your account should have been changed to one of the current editions (Standard/Enterprise etc).

The retention period is a maximum of 1 day for the standard edition and 90 days for the enterprise edition. I would expect that your account should have been set to Enterprise, so the max retention time should be 90 days:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-time-travel.html#data-retention-period

Anyway, you can just try to set the retention time for a table to 90 days to check it.